# Why won't collectstatic copy my static files?

Tags: django, static

I have a `MyApp/static/MyApp` directory.

When I run `./manage.py collectstatic`, I expect the MyApp directory be copied to `STATIC_ROOT`, but it doesn't.

I have `DownloadedApp/static/DownloadedApp` as well and its copied to `STATIC_ROOT fine`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What are the `STATIC_ROOT`, `STATICFILES_FINDERS`, and `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your `settings.py`?

When `collectstatic` is run, the default `STATICFILES_FINDERS` value `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder` will collect your static files from any paths that you have in `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

The other default `STATICFILES_FINDERS` value `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder` will look in the `/static/` folder of any apps in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

All of the static files that are found will be placed in the specified `STATIC_ROOT` directory.

[Check out this link to the collectstatic docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic)

[And this link an explanation of the various static settings in settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-files)

You can also use `python manage.py findstatic` to see which directories `collectstatic` will look in.

Comment: django cached static_root static_url settings.py won't reflect the change I made in file.

Comment: `python manage.py findstatic` renders `Error: Enter at least one static file.`

Comment: @antonagestam `python manage.py findstatic -v 3 dummy` will output the paths after the error.

Answer (score 5):

That just happened to me and I accidentally put the app's static files directory in the .gitignore file.  So on my local machine it got collected just fine, but in production the static files were actually missing (gitignored).

Comment: This happened to me, but in Heroku, in the `.slugignore` file instead of the  `.gitignore`

Comment: This makes no sense to me: doesn't collectstatic create those directories when it's run? I'm having the same problem (over and over, for different reasons, it seems)

Comment: @lysdexia you have to differentiate between an app's static files folder and the project's static files folder.  When you run ``collectstatic`` it copies the individual apps' static folders into the project's static folder.  If you gitignored your app's static folder it doesn't get pushed into the production environment and hence doesn't get collected.

Comment: Happened to me )) Thanks for saving my time!

Answer (score 5):

just do this and make the naming convention same

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

**static** directory contains all off your project assets

**assets** directory will create automatic when u run this cmd

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

this will copy all static folder content into assets folder

hope this helps :)

Comment: I followed the exact same steps, but it has not copied the files in assets folder

Answer (score 1):

your are missing the STATIC_ROOT where your static files going to be copied just
add this line in your settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
```

your settings.py looks like this :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
```

#added manully

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
    
]
```

remember to add STAIC_ROOT path in urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static




urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("" ,include("home.urls")),
 
]+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

After all of it you can run :

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

it will create a staticfiles folder for you in your Dir

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because while investigating a bug occurring on certain dates, changed my computer date and time.

Hence it disturbed things like collectstatic, and also my browser history.

Don't change your computer date and time.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression the comparison would be content based. It turned out to be date based. So, don't mess with your files after `collecstatic`.

Answer (score 0):

One Quick work-around, although this does not fix it or explain WHY it's happening, is to:

1. go to your project's file directory & rename your project's
   'static' folder to something else like 'static-old'
2. create a new,empty folder called 'static' in your project directory
3. now if you run `python manage.py collectstatic` it will see that nothing is
   in your static folder and will copy ALL static files over.

Answer (score 0):

if you have setup everything properly for static and you are using `nginx` then enter this command

```
sudo nginx -t
```

You will see `error` why your static files aren't being served and fix that specific error

In my case I gave wrong path in my `nginx config`

```
location /static {
        root /home/ubuntu/myproject/app/static/;
    }
```