# Django Error pipeline.exceptions.CompilerError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, django

Whenever I run the command `python manage.py collectstatic`, I recieve an error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\doors\lib\site-packages\pipeline\compilers\__init__.py", line 146, in execute_command
    error_output=text_type(e))
pipeline.exceptions.CompilerError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

[Stack trace here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIM6c.png)

Comment: Please look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472259/why-collectstatic-wont-copy-my-static-files

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because some of the files listed in the PIPELINE configuration were not found for compilation.

check the lib. https://django-pipeline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html