# Django 3.2.8: 0 static files copied to '/static'

Tags: django, django-admin, collectstatic, django-static

This error occurs when performing command `python manage.py collectstatic`:

> 0 static files copied to '/home/project'.

That means there is no changes and my static files already exist in the destination but in this folder only one file:

```
static/
      - staticfiles.json
```

But I want all my CSS, js, HTML for panel admin to be in it.

**Django Settings:**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_ROOT,
)
```

**urls.py**

```
...
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I also tried these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66143429/staticfiles-not-copied-to-static-root-0-static-files-copied), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472259/why-wont-collectstatic-copy-my-static-files)  but no results were found.

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS` should not contain `STATIC_ROOT`, do you not get an error telling you that when you try to run `collectstatic`?

Comment: @IainShelvington No. output is `0 static files copied to '/static'.`

Comment: What output do you get from `python manage.py version`? You should remove the leading slash from the join for STATIC_ROOT, otherwise you set it to "/static" from the root of your filesystem: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`

Comment: Can you tell us the path where you have placed your assets? Normally, it's places somewhere in `/templates/staticfiles/`.

Comment: Hello @Saeed try to convert your ``STATICFILES_DIRS`` to list instead of tuple I know it's weird but when you run ``python manage.py collectstatic`` it's giving you path to your root directory instead it should give you path to your **STATIC_ROOT** eg. ***``0 static files copied to '/home/project/static'.``***

Comment: @IainShelvington `python manage.py version` => `3.2.8`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Thank you for your answer. You were right. Some of my settings were wrong elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define all paths with [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) where Django will look for static files.
For example:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates/staticfiles")]
```

When you run [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic), Django will copy all found files in all your paths from `STATICFILES_DIRS` into [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#static-root).

In your case, Django will copy all files to:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/static/")
```

After that, your static files are accessible through your defined [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#static-url) URL. In your case:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

settings.py

```
import os
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('demo/',Demo.as_view(),name='demo')
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Add Your File in folder-
static->demo_folder->staticfiles.json

python3 manage.py collecstatic

Comment: Without `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your settings.py file, django will not grab for your static assets. By the way, it should be `collectstatic` and not `collecstatic`.

Comment: Thanks for valuable information...In this some spelling mistakes.....!! Thank you